# Why are my commits via go-git dated 1970?

Tags: git, go, go-git

I am committing changes via go-git:

```
import (
  "github.com/tcnksm/go-gitconfig"
  "github.com/walterjwhite/go-application/libraries/logging"

  "gopkg.in/src-d/go-git.v4"
  "gopkg.in/src-d/go-git.v4/plumbing/object"
)

func stackoverflowCommit(R *git.Repository, W *git.Worktree) {
  username, err := gitconfig.Username()
  logging.Panic(err)

  email, err := gitconfig.Email()
  logging.Panic(err)

  _, err = W.Commit("commit message goes here", &git.CommitOptions{Author: &object.Signature{Name: username, Email: email}})

  logging.Panic(err)
}
```

In my logs, I see this:

```
Date:   Thu Jan 1 00:00:00 1970 +0000
```

Is this expected behavior?  I don't see anyway for me to pass in a date.  A quick inspection of the source shows the Commit object doesn't have any references to date ...

Is that right, or am I missing something?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but midnight January 1 1970 is the zero value of [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), a widely used measure of time in software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass in the current time to `object.Signature`. [The documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/src-d/go-git.v4@v4.13.1/plumbing/object?tab=doc#Signature) for `object.Signature` shows that you can provide a `time.Time` type.
 This is also demonstrated in [an example](https://github.com/src-d/go-git/blob/v4.13.1/_examples/commit/main.go) on GitHub. Be sure to import `"time"`.

```golang
_, err = W.Commit("commit message goes here", &git.CommitOptions{
    Author: &object.Signature{
        Name: username, 
        Email: email, 
        When: time.Now(),
    },
})
```

Comment: Thanks - I will get my eyes checked.